# How can I parent an object whilst animating?

Tags: unity, animation

Much like in Blender where you can parent an object to another, or the Armature, is it possible to parent an object to another, so when animating, the child object moves with the parent?

I've tried dropping the object I want influenced onto the character's parent object in the hierarchy and accessed it via the Animation tab. I added the object as a property and adjusted it's position, but the results have been pretty mixed.

How can I have an object automatically follow the animation without manually adjusting its curves for each frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity, your Armature which was imported from Blender should be modeled as a hierarchy of GameObjects. You can make GameObjects children of these bones to have them move with the bone during an animation, just like you would in Blender. No further animation changes are needed unless you need the objects to reposition beyond just following the parent.

In the following image ([taken from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775225/creating-an-animation-on-model-in-unity)), the wrench is a GameObject which is not a part of the imported model/animation. Its parent is the hand. Whenever an animation plays, the wrench will follow the hand.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. And to think, I was so close to achieving this... lol